# QML Changing style of TextField's menu

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I would like to customize style of my application and I'm stuck on the style of `TextField` pop-up menu.

`TextField.style` allows to customize the look of `TextField` but it doesn't contain the style of the menu. According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#menu-prop) there is a property `menu` containing the `Menu` so I tried something like this:

```
TextField {
   menu.style: MenuStyle {
       //...
   }
}
```

Code above complains that property `style` is non-existent so it's not exactly `Menu`, it's `Component` used to create the menu and I don't know if there is a way to get through it to the actual `Menu`. Documentation only mentions that `TextField.menu` can be set to `null` to disable it completely and doesn't provide other use cases.

So is there a way to get to the menu of `TextField` and change its style?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should post all relevant code here. Anyway, you cannot define the `TextField` menu and its style separately. See the example below to customize `Menu` style and adding it to the `TextField` inline:

```js
TextField {
    text: "text here"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    menu: Menu {
        style: MenuStyle {
            frame: Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                border.color: "purple"
            }
            itemDelegate {
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "yellow"
                }
                label: Text {
                    color: styleData.selected ? "red" : "blue"
                    text: styleData.text
                }
            }
        }
        MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
        MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
    }
}
```

See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-menustyle.html) page for complete list of `MenuStyle` properties.

Comment: Is there a way to change Menu style without reimplementing the Menu? As I understand I would need to supply my own actions for "Cut", "Copy", etc. in this solution.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. `TextField.menu` is `Component` and it just has no property `style`.

Comment: Thanks @folibis, so what properties does it have? `TextField.menu.url` pointed me to file `Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/EditMenu_base.qml` which implements the default menu.  I copied it to my project and changed it a little bit to accept custom menu style, and bound it to my TextField. It's messy but it works.

Comment: Yes, it looks that the only way to do that.

Comment: @krzysiek: do you try to use this menu on iOS or Android ? Because I am not successfully.

Comment: @LiborB. No, I only tried to use it in desktop application.